# VB.NET Starting a process, denying it web access

Tags: vb.net, process

Is it possible to spawn a process using Visual Basic .NET and denying it network access?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is set up a Windows user account that does not have network access.  You can then supply this user's name and password in the [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) structure when calling [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx).